# How do I block a user doing too many requests without blocking an entire organization?

Tags: google, spam

We have a running website and some of the content comes from a paid API. Our website is free. Our main concern at the moment is people using our website as a "free" way to get at the underlying data in an automated fashion. We've thought about a simple IP block that would block a user if they request "X" amount of pages within "Y" amount of time. By doing so we run the risk of blocking out an entire organization...(e.g. if there are 100 people from Company A (or from an Apartment building, etc.) that use our service and they all have the same IP address we DON'T want to block that.)

In other words, how does Google (or even some other search engines) block a particular user? (I've been personally blocked by Google for a few minutes but my colleague on the same IP address as me and the same Browser/UA-Agent as me was surfing fine without running into a captcha, etc.)

EDIT: This website will not have registered users.

Comment: Set it absurdly high for legitimate use but low enough to protect the data, and have a "blacklisted in error" form so people can get exemptions made.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a way to identify a user. Does not have to be via IP address. It could be via:

- Identifier in a cookie
- Username
- User agent fingerprinting

The last method is an interesting one and not an exact science. There's been some [great work done on that by EFF](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) for example.